# How to execute Observable consistently and combine result

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an issue with Observable chain and can't found decision.
I need to wait for result from IndexedDB, push it to next request and combine two results in last Observable.
Here is example:

```
const first$ = Database.gelAll(store); // return Observable
first.mergeMap((data) => {
  const uuids = data.map((v) => {
    return v.uuid;
  });

  // here i need to send request with 'uuids' array and combine result with 
     values from first request
  const second$ = database.find(store, {'uuid': uuids}); // return Observable
});
```

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: You haven't told us what the issue is. And `mergeMap` creates and returns a new Observable, but it doesn't look like you're assigning it to anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you're trying to make it so the end result of your observable is an object containing both the result from `Database.gelAll` and also the result from `database.find`. To do that, you'll just need to add a .map statement after the `database.find`, and return it to the merge map.

```
Database.gelAll(store)
  .mergeMap((data) => {
    const uuids = data.map((v) => v.uuid);

    return database.find(store, {'uuid': uuids})
      .map((databaseResult) => {
        // Combine with data in some fashion
        return {
          firstData: data,
          secondData: databaseResult
        }
      });
  })

  .subscribe(objectWithBothFirstDataAndSecondData => {
    console.log(objectWithBothFirstDataAndSecondData)
  });
```

Also, you should consider whether `.mergeMap` is appropriate. If `.gelAll` only emits one value then it should be ok, but in most cases, `.switchMap` or `.concatMap` is a better choice than `.mergeMap`. With mergeMap you have no guarantee of the order. Switchmap ensures that only the latest is used, concatMap ensures that everything gets through, but they get through in the same order they were asked for.

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer i was looking for and thanks for explanation of Map.